# Get first letter of last word of each span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the first letter of the last word in every span on the page. I will then add this as a class (used for filtering).

Here is what I have so far:

```
$('.each-artist span').each(function() {
    var artistName = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); // get text, convert to lowercase
    var firstLetterSplice = artistName.slice(0, 1); // get first letter
    $(this).parent().parent('.each-artist').addClass(firstLetterSplice); // add as class
});
```

So, this works fairly successfully, it takes the text of each `.each-artist span`, lowercases it, splices it to find first letter then adds this first letter as a class.

The only issue is I need to get the last word of each `.each-artist span`, not the first, then get the first letter of this last word and apply it as a class.

I have a jsFiddle set up for testing: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rZbwQ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, just split by word boundary and then get the last word

```
$('.each-artist span').each(function () {
    var artistName = $(this).text().toLowerCase().split(/\b/);
    var firstLetterSplice = artistName.pop().slice(0, 1);
    $(this).closest('.each-artist').addClass(firstLetterSplice);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rZbwQ/2/)

Comment: This is great thanks. Three things. Can you explain `.split(/\b/)`, `.pop()` and what if there is just one name? (Sorry, should have included this in my jsFiddle.

Comment: `split()` splits a string, `\b` is a regex for [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), so it returns an array with the words, and even if there's only one word, an array with that word is returned, so it still works. `pop()` gets the last value in an array.

Comment: Also, while I'm here, as the `.each-artist span` text is being generated via the CMS (first name/last name field), if the last name first is left blank it adds a space to my span. How can I ignore the space? http://jsfiddle.net/rZbwQ/5/

Comment: ^^ Guess I need to keep learning my functions ;) Thanks again!